# How to find if the distance between destination and source is less than 5?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to write a method that will return true if the distance between two nodes is less than 5 in a graph. I try to write with the minimum distances algorithm as shown :

```
class Movie{ //this is the node in the graph
    String name;
    List<Movie> movies;
}

private static boolean isgoodMovies(Movie origin, Movie destination){
    Queue<Movie> nextToVisit = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<Movie> visited = new HashSet<>();
    HashMap<Movie, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();
    nextToVisit.add(origin);
    distances.put(origin, 0);
    while (!nextToVisit.isEmpty()){
        Movie visitedNode = nextToVisit.remove();
        if(visited.equals(destination)) {break;}
        if(!visited.contains(visitedNode))   {continue;}
        visited.add(visitedNode);

        for (Movie movie : visitedNode.movies) {
            nextToVisit.add(movie);
            distances.put(movie, distances.get(visitedNode) + 1);
        }
    }


    return distances.get(origin) < 5;

}
```

By modifying the minimum distances algorithm, I return the boolean based on the distance of the origin node. I want to optimize it in a way that I do not use a hashmap or any collection, simply having a distance variable. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the recursion here if the number of movies isn't huge (you can get `StackOverflowError` if the number of method invocations exceeds the maximum stack depth). So, don't use any `Collection` except for a `HashSet` as shown below:

```
private static boolean isGoodMovies(Movie origin, Movie destination) {
    Set<Movie> visited = new HashSet<>();
    return isGoodMovies(origin, destination, visited, 0); 
}

private static boolean isGoodMovies(Movie current, Movie destination, visited, int depth) {
    if (depth >= 5) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (destination.equals(current)) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean isGood = false;
    for (Movie child : current.movies) {
        if (!visited.contains(child) {
            visited.add(child);
            isGood |= isGoodMovies(child, destination, depth + 1);    
        }
    } 
    
    return isGood;
}
```